# NextJS App with Auth0 and Redux failing to retrieve Auth session on manual refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, auth0

Problem: if I refresh a page, getInitialProps trigger but it gets me the error describe on the bottom of the page which points out an issue going all the way to my redux wrapper on /_app.js, which I believe to be the issue. This behavior only happens on refresh page. If I go from a page that has no getInitialProps and then navigate client side to the page with getInitialProps it works fine. If I then do a manual refresh of the page it triggers the error.

This is my setup for redux and I've tried it with the Class based version with same results so that's not the issue.

/_app.js

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import withRedux from "next-redux-wrapper";
import { initStore } from "../store";

import "./styles.scss";

const MyApp = props => {
  const { Component, pageProps, store } = props;
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
};

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
  const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps
    ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    : {};
  return { pageProps };
};

export default withRedux(initStore)(MyApp);
```

this is the `getInitialProps` on the index.js page
/pages/index.js

```
OpenApplications.getInitialProps = async ({ store }) => {

  const stateDB = await getApplications();

  // populate state with all applications from DB
  await store.dispatch(populateApplicationsState(stateDB));

  return store;
};
```

this is the internal API setup with Auth
/api/applications.js

```
import auth0 from "../../../../lib/auth/auth0";
// auth0.requireAuthentication ensures that only authenticated users access this internal API path
export default auth0.requireAuthentication(async (req, res) => {
  // get user profile from Auth0 on the server side
  const { user } = await auth0.getSession(req);

process the rest of the stuff...
})
```

this is the code behind the Auth0 init config
.../auth/auth0.js

```
import { initAuth0 } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import config from "./config";

export default initAuth0({
  clientId: config.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: config.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  scope: config.AUTH0_SCOPE,
  domain: config.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  redirectUri: config.REDIRECT_URI,
  postLogoutRedirectUri: config.POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI,
  session: {
    cookieSecret: config.SESSION_COOKIE_SECRET,
    cookieLifetime: config.SESSION_COOKIE_LIFETIME,
    cookieSameSite: "lax",
    storeIdToken: true,
    storeRefreshToken: true,
    storeAccessToken: true
  }
});
```

This is the Application tab on Chrome Dev Tools and it shows the a0state and a0session. When I refresh, the state disappears but the cookie stays. On an unprotected page it then comes back after I assume making a call to check the session is valid but on a protected page it goes into the error above.

[image: Application tab on Chrome Dev Tools]

error if `requireAuthtentication` is taken OFF

[image: error without Auth]

error if `requireAuthentication` is ON
[image: error with Auth]

So my suspicion is that whenever a manual page refresh is onset, auth0 loses the state and it doesn't pass it in the `req` to the API so that it fails the auth check and also it fails to get the session from the user. If I remove the `auth0.requireAuthentication`, it still fails because I'm dependent on the `user` which comes from `auth0.getSession(req);` which fails nonetheless and that triggers an error anyway because `user` comes `undefined`. What I think it's happening is that the session is not being passed on correctly due to the Redux wrapper setup that doesn't pass the necessary info or triggers the necessary Auth for that info to be there. At this point I'm a bit lost as all these tools are new to me and I'm not sure where it's going wrong and where to fix it and since it's 3 different libraries interacting it gets even harder. Help figure this super annoying bug :)

I checked everywhere and couldn't find a solution or a similar setup to get a comparison and find out a potential mistake I've done on my setup. Everything is pretty much like the examples on the docs for the different tools `next-wrapper-redux`/`nextjs-auth0`/`next`

Comment: have you solved it?